# TCPDF chinese font detection

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

how to switches to check or use which font either tradi or simplified when the user input ? For example, if the user enter traditional font and my system set as simplified , sometimes it will show simplified font, some will gone missing not showing in PDF. Is there any method to use both together or case switches? Your help will be much appreciated :). Thank you.

```
$pdf->SetFont('fangzhentraditional', '', 13,'',false);

$pdf->SetFont('fangzhensimplified', '', 13,'',false);

$pdf->Output('','S');
```

Comment: no clue about font detection, but from a logical standpoint why don't you have a select box so the user can select which one they want. i doubt font detection won't be 100% accurate anyways.

Comment: Noted about the select option for them to choose, it's quite a good way also. Will try it out. But few of my clients, have so called "special name" the first name is traditional font and middle is simplified and last name is traditional. hmmmmmmmmm